# How to set flag for time interval in T-SQL

Tags: sql, loops, t-sql, datetime, case

I have a query that has InsertDate and flag field. I need to set the flag to Y for the first 10 minutes, and every 12 hours after that. This is what I have so far, but hard-coded is not an ideal at all.

> select InsertDate, case when DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MAX(InsertDate),
> GETDATE()) <= 10 then 'Y' when DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MAX(InsertDate),
> GETDATE())  = 720 then 'Y' when DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MAX(InsertDate),
> GETDATE())  = 1440 then 'Y' Else 'N' end as flag

How do I update my syntax to get away from hard-coded? Thank you for any helps

Comment: that is not valid sql as is.   Sample table definition, data and desired output would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is not valid SQL to start with: it has no `from` clause, and having both `insertdate` and `max(insertdate)` in the `select` clause makes no sense.

Bottom line, I think you want modulo artithmetics:

```
case
    when datediff(minute, insertdate, getdate()) <= 10     then 'y' 
    when datediff(minute, insertdate, getdate()) % 720 = 0 then 'y'
    else 'n' 
end as flag
```

`<expr> % 720 = 0` reads as: `<expr>` is a multiple of `720`.

Comment: Modulo artithmetics is what I need as you mentioned and your answer solves my problem. Thank you!